# 301 redirect entire website to a single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website that I would like to implement a 301 redirect for an entire site (every page on the website) to a single page. Basically I have an old blog and I want to 301 redirect every page on that blog to our Facebook page instead.

When I search google I get the response to do it this way:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.facebook.com/whatever
```

This works, however the problem I am running into is if someone types in a subfolder of the website such as: www.oldwebsite.com/subfolder it will redirect to https://www.facebook.com/whateversubfolder which is not what I need.

I need every possible page on oldwebsite.com to redirect to the single page https://www.facebook.com/whatever. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://www.facebook.com/whatever
```